# Is there a way to transfer data from one page to another page with Vue?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a login page made in Vue, but after I log in I need to transfer the username to his/her dashboard. I have tried different solutions like an event bus but it does not work. Are there any other solutions?

This is what I already tried:

```
// In my login page I have this after the user presses login 
bus.$emit('Login', this.Name);

// This is what I have in my dashboard page
created() {
  bus.$on('Login', obj => {
    this.currentName = obj;
  });
}
```

I expect that the username, which is entered at the login page, to be on the dashboard page too.

Comment: Recommend using vuex for this

Comment: Can you use vuex (or other state manager)?

Comment: Just for that you don't need **Vuex**. If you're paging then I gues you use **vue-router** - if yes, then you can send info (as props or as query params) through the router: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

Comment: There are a lot of ways to share data between two vue components. The event bus method you're currently trying should work. If it's not working for you, then there is some other part of your code that isn't working as you're expecting it to. Try making a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just for that you don't need **Vuex**. If you're paging then I gues you use **vue-router** - if yes, then you can send info (as props or as query params) through the router: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a robust application vuex is definitely the way to go.

If you are just practicing there are a couple of ways you get the username

1) localStorage - when the user clicks "Login" you can set a variable to store the user name. Note that this value would remain after logging unless you remove it.

at login method

```
localStorage.setItem('username', this.name)
```

dashboard view

```
<span>{{username}}</span>

<script>
 computed: {
   username() {
         return localStorage.getItem('username')
   }
}
</script>
```

2) router parameter - when you navigate to the dashboard view from the login view, you add a key to the url that is holding the user name

at login method

```
this.$router.push({path: '/dashboard', query: {username: this.name }})
```

at dashboard view

```
<span>{{username}}</span>

 <script>
  data() {
   return {
       username: ''
    }
 },
created() {
   this.username = this.$route.query.username
}
```

on your bus.$on method you could try passing in the expected value and setting it more explicitly like this..

```
created() {
  bus.$on('Login', ({name}) => {
    this.currentName = name;
  });
}
```

also note that in order to use the event bus you have to import an instance of it, I believe it does not work out of the box

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```